# jQuery get data-name as value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was previously using

```
     jQuery( "select#colour option:selected" ).each(function() {
        value += "colour-" + jQuery( this ).val();
    });
```

This took the selected value from a dropdown and constructed another value with it.

I am now trying to modify this to get the value (data-name) from the following html...

```
<div class="select-option" data-name="apple">
<div class="select-option selected" data-name="orange">
<div class="select-option" data-name="banana">
```

Anyone got an similar example they can point me at?

Answer (score 4):

use `.data('name')` to get the `data-name` attribute value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select-option').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    console.log(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-option" data-name="apple">
<div class="select-option selected" data-name="orange">
<div class="select-option" data-name="banana">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var value;

$('.select-option').each(function(){
  value+=$(this).attr('data-name'); //or $(this).data('name');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data)

```
jQuery( ".select-option" ).each(function() {
        value += "colour-" + jQuery( this ).data("name");
 })
```